# how to update Ldap user attribute value for all users

Tags: ldap-query, opendj

can you please help me on this, Currenlty in our opendj ldap user store, we are storing `Full Name( attribute:cn)="Lastname Firstname"`, now our requirement is to update all the users `Full name(cn)` to `Firstname Lastname"(attributes)`, can you please help me to get the ldap query.

Thanks,

Comment: What have you thus far tried?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with a single query with LDAP. 
You need to read each user and modify the CN attribute. If CN is used for naming entries, you should use ModDN for each modify, otherwise simple Modify operation is enough.
Alternately you could export the data to LDIF, do the transformation in the LDIF text file and reimport it.

Regards.